# Npgsql exception: Column c.consrc does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, entity-framework, npgsql

I have a Postgres 12 database that currently only consists of one simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.messages
(
    sender text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone,
    message_id bigint,
    text text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    priority bigint,
    parameters text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
```

No I want to use Npgsql to build a GUI with C# and Entity Framework. I installed the Nuget package:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework6.Npgsql
```

and it succeeded:

```
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework6.Npgsql 6.4.0' to TestClient
```

Next, I installed the Npgsql integration for VS 2019 ([found here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration)). When I try to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project by right-clicking it in the solution explorer, I can add a connection and the connection test ist successful (done in the Wizard). I can go on and select my table, but as soon as I press Finish, I get an error:

[image]

This is the console output:

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> Npgsql.PostgresException: 42703: Column
>   c.consrc does not exist

What can I do?

Comment: Which .Net Framework are you using ? If it is .Net Core, you need Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostGreSQL

Comment: I'm using/targetting .NET Framework 4.6 (not .NET Core) with Windows Forms, so the package should be alright, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PG12 removed the pg_constraint.consrc, this is tracked by PG12 removed the pg_constraint.consrc. Downgrading to PG11 should work until a fix is released.

Comment: Note: have just published EntityFramework6.Npgsql 6.4.1 with a fix for this, can you give that a try?

Comment: It works now, thanks for the update! But the [next problem is already there ;-)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277281/how-to-deal-with-a-text-array-field-type-in-npgsql)

Answer (score 1):

For postgres 12+ (I am currently using version 16), one can use the following query to list constraints and their details for a certain table.

```sql
SELECT
    conname AS constraint_name,
    contype AS constraint_type,
    conkey AS constrained_columns,
    confkey AS referenced_columns,
    confrelid::regclass AS referenced_table,
    conrelid::regclass AS constrained_table,
    CASE
        WHEN contype = 'f' THEN 'FOREIGN KEY'
        WHEN contype = 'u' THEN 'UNIQUE'
        WHEN contype = 'p' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
        WHEN contype = 'c' THEN 'CHECK'
    END AS constraint_category,
    CASE
        WHEN contype = 'c' THEN
            (SELECT pg_get_constraintdef(oid) FROM pg_constraint WHERE oid = c.oid)
    END AS check_expression
FROM
    pg_constraint c
WHERE
    conrelid = 'table_name'::regclass;
```